# New activity - New menu

Tags: android, android-activity, menu

I moved on with my development in Android applications and have now added a new activity which is activated with a press on a listview item.

**The problem**

My new activity shows the menu from my main activity. This is fairly unexpected. Question is, how can I solve this?

**What have I done so far**

In my main activity, I have created a menu (menu.xml) which is added like this:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
    return true;
}    


@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle item selection
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.refresh:
        new DownloadXmlTask().execute();
        return true;
    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

This works as expected.

Now I start the new activity like this:

```
//lv is (ofc) my listview
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

        EntryObject obj = entries.get(position);

        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString("title", obj.title);
        bundle.putString("teaser", obj.teaser);
        bundle.putString("description", obj.description);
        bundle.putString("date", obj.date);
        bundle.putString("key", obj.key);
        bundle.putString("mp4", obj.mp4);

        Intent myIntent = new Intent();
        myIntent.setClassName("dk.jyskebank.programserie.tolvsytten", "dk.jyskebank.programserie.tolvsytten.DetailedActivity");
        myIntent.putExtras(bundle);

        startActivity(myIntent); 

    }
  });
```

The activity starts, I have my information from the Bundle object with me and in the new activity I need a new menu (detail_menu.xml).
I then implement this the same way as before:

```
   @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu detail_menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.detail_menu, detail_menu);
        return true;
    }    


    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle item selection
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.share:
            startSharing();
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
```

The content of menu.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@+id/refresh" android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_refresh" android:title="@string/refresh" />
    <item android:id="@+id/featured" android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_home" android:title="@string/featured" />
    <item android:id="@+id/most_recent" android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_day" android:title="@string/most_recent" />
    <item android:id="@+id/favorites" android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_emoticons" android:title="@string/favorites" />
    <item android:id="@+id/rated" android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_star" android:title="@string/top_rated" />
    <item android:id="@+id/menu_more" android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_more" android:title="@string/more" />
</menu>
```

The content of detail_menu.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@+id/share" android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_share" android:title="@string/share" />
</menu>
```

Comment: +1 for explanation. could you please add the `menu.xml` and `detail_menu.xml`, so that attachments with question become more clear.

Comment: I updated the questions with the xml.

Comment: @Repox just few question 1. Did you tried clean(menu Project->Clean...) the Project 2. why youre using `myIntent.setClassName("dk.jyskebank.programserie.tolvsytten", "dk.jyskebank.programserie.tolvsytten.DetailedActivity");` not  `myIntent = new Intent(this, DetailedActivity.class);`?

Comment: @Selvin 1. I did that now and that made it work. Can you explain why? 2. I found an example for opening the new activity [here](http://developer.android.com/resources/faq/commontasks.html#opennewscreen) which is why I wrote it the way I did. Your suggestion is better (visually at least).

Comment: @Repox only FSM(and Google but i'm not sure about this) knows why ADT sometimes don't rebuild resources... suggestion ... not only visually .. if you rename your Activity Eclipse will refactor this too if you have class name in string - doesn't :)

Comment: @Selvin Great, thanks. Could you please provide an answer for this, so I can accept and close? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok in comments i suggested Repox to Clean project .... well and it helped :)
It happend to me many times: resources doesn't exists even if they are in generated R.java or resources in R.jave points to not exaclly which i want ... anyway Clean always help(or deleteing R.java)

Repox knows how to use SO and he wana keep his "100% accept rate"
thats why i made my response here :)

Answer (score 0):

try calling `super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);` before inflating your menu.

Comment: Thank you for suggestion, but this caused an exception android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f070001

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks fine. Try refreshing the project (select it in the package explorer and press <kbd>F5</kbd>) and then cleaning it (go to <kbd>Project > Clean...</kbd> from the window menu).